# Сравнить переменную с одним из элементов списка

Tags: python

Есть переменная с числом

```
a = 520025768
```

необходимо сравнить a со списком List в котором содержится это:

```
['3186049208', '520025768', '937243470', '2531853314', '2577960494', '3113369241', '3113369241', '2735408045', '2531854391', '1812814302', '520028244', '1934445778', '2960964943', '2960959302', '1988115969', '2735423107', '1225722045', '2735394070']
```

как это можно сделать?

Comment: Сравнить в каком смысле? Есть ли `a` в списке? Тогда можно так: `str(a) in li`, где `li` — Ваш список.

Comment: какой результат вы хотите получить?

Comment: @MaxU Есть ли в этом списке дубликаты и если есть - сравнить с a

Comment: Не ясно что вы имеете в виду говоря сравнить скалярное значение а, со списком.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы имеете в виду, что нужно найти в списке элемент `a`, то:

```
for i in mylist:
    if i == str(a):
        print('Object', i, 'in mylist.')
```

Если вам нужно проверить список на дубликаты и сравнить дубликат с `a`, то:

```
duplicate = [k for k,v in Counter(mylist).items() if v>1]
if a in duplicate:
    print('a in duplicate')
else:
    print('a not in duplicate')
```