# Массивы python zxc

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть массив:

```
characters = ['first', 'second'] 
u = input() #Допустим u = first
```

мне нужно сравнить u с characters, но так не получается. Я пытался сделать:

```
if u == characters[0:1]:
```

Но это естественно не вышло. Далее я нашел решение, но оно немного меня не устраивает:

```
if u == 'First':
    pass
if u == 'Second':
    pass
```

Оно длиннее, и дольше пишется, Чтобы перечислить так всех гервоев, уйдет их количество x 2.
Есть решение?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сравнить переменную с одним из элементов списка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1028769/%d0%a1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй `if ... in ...`:

```
if u in characters:
    pass
```

Comment: Получилось, спасибо большое! помогли